# Inner Join PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to join two table together with this query

```
select comments.* ,username, title
from comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.user_id 
INNER JOIN posts ON comments.post_id = posts.post_id;
```

the result given back is `column reference "username" is ambiguous`

Comment: Qualify the username column with the table from which you want to get it.

Comment: Why do multiple tables have a column called `username`?  That should only be in `users`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns should be in form `table.column`

> select comments.* ,username, title

should be

`select comments.* ,YOUR_TABLE.username, YOUR_TABLE.title`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    SELECT comments.* ,users.username, title
    FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.user_id = users.user_id 
    INNER JOIN posts ON comments.post_id = posts.post_id;
```

Note the `users.username` in the query above.

As an aside, you shouldn't have a column `username` in multiple tables. You might want to look into "normalizing" your data.